# Border around list item in CSS/SCSS

Tags: html, css, sass

how can I draw a border around the list item that includes everything inside this list item? When I add a border to the list item only the a tag (Link 1) gets a border, but the ul tag will be ignored for some reason. A very simple prototype is working, but here I cannot find the issue.

HTML

```
<header>
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="..." />
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Text 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Text 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

CSS/SCSS

```
nav {
    float: right;
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: $black;
      display: block;
      &:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    }
    ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        ul {
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          li {
            width: 100%;
          }
          a {
            padding: 10px 0px;
          }
        }
        &:hover {
          ul {
            display: block;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    > ul {
      > li {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        > a {
          padding: 10px 0px;
          border-left: 1px solid #000;
          display: block;
        }
        &:first-child {
          margin: 0;
          a {
            border: 0;
          }
```

Comment: Move the border from the `a` to the `li`?

Answer (score 1):

Your SCSS is very specific as to which element gets a border.

```
nav > ul > a {
  ...
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  ...
}
```

So that means the border is for

```
<nav>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a> // This elements gets the border.
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Text 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Text 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But if you want the first `li` to receive a border then you should edit this part of your CSS to be:

```
> li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    border-left: 1px solid #000; // this will give it a border
}
```